# Logger is not able to separate data between different files

Tags: java, logging, web-scraping

I made a sort of web scraper in Java that downloads html code and writes it in a logger.

The code for the data miner is the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;



public class Scraping {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

    public static void getData(String address, int val) throws IOException {
        // Make a URL to the web page
        URL url = new URL(address);

        // Get the input stream through URL Connection
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is =con.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;

        FileHandler fh;
        fh = new FileHandler(Integer.toString(val)+".txt");
        LOGGER.addHandler(fh);
        //SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
        fh.setFormatter(new MyFormatter());

        LOGGER.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.FINE);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            toTable(line);
        }
    }

    /*arrange data in table*/
    private static void toTable(String line){
        if(line.startsWith("<tr ><th scope=\"row\" class=\"left \" data-append-csv=") && !line.contains("ts_pct")){
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, line);
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the code once it gives me the correct output, but I need to run it multiple times in a for loop (sending another address and index i as val, giving Logger a different name for every iteration), and when I do that, the Logger file appends new data from files that should be in a different file.

So, index 0 gets data for val 0, 1, and 2, instead of having just val 0 data in there.

The file handler boolean append doesn't seem to make any difference for my program's output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,web scraping isn't data mining. No advanced statistics involved.

Secondly,don't abuse loggers for IO.

Logging is to make sure you get some debug information when your program fails, in a configurable way (so don't use `GLOBAL_LOGGER` but each class should have a different logger), and you can see what is happening.

For writing your output files, use the standard OutputStream etc. of your programming language. Don't try to reroute your output completely through logging.